# How do you use the output from an async result in app.config.ts?

Tags: async-await, expo

I'm building a mobile app using Expo. I've switched to using a dynamic `app.config.ts` file in order to leverage environment variables and have different configurations for dev, staging and production.

When in 'dev' configuration, I'd like to be able to set a config value to the output of a web request (basically, the ngrok public_url obtained from `localhost:4040/api/tunnels`).

However, as I understand it from the Expo documentation, the dynamic configuration in `app.config.ts` does NOT support Promises (and there's an error when I try to use it). This is very unfortunate as it would allow me to solve my problem immediately. As such, I'm now looking for a workaround.

What options are there for me to use the output of an async (Promise) function such as this within  my Expo configuration file?

Comment: If you're using **EAS**, you can use EAS Build functions to fetch the ngrok public URL and add it to your app configuration. This method is similar to using Expo Config Plugins, but it's integrated with EAS Build and might be easier to use.

Comment: This won't work when running the server locally in dev mode (npx expo start) which is what I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process looks like:

```
App Config --> │app.config.ts│ --> Expo Config
                    |
                    V
             Async Operation
                    |
                    V
            │Fetch ngrok URL│
                    |
                    V
            Set Config Value
```

> running the server locally in dev mode (`npx expo start`) which is what I am trying to achieve here.

Since [`app.config.ts`](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/) in Expo does *not* support asynchronous operations, you might consider:

- creating a separate script to run before `npx expo start` which performs the asynchronous operation to get the `ngrok` URL.
- having this script write the result to a `.env` file or some other form of temporary storage.
- modifying your `app.config.ts` to synchronously read from this temporary storage.

```bash
              │app.config.ts│
                      |
                      │   Sync
                      │
              | Read .env File |
                      │
                      V
             Set Config Value
```

Create a script `setup-dev-env.js`, using [Node.js File system `fs` API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and, for instance, using [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // or any other fetch library

async function fetchNgrokUrl() {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels');
  const data = await response.json();
  const publicUrl = data.tunnels.find(tunnel => tunnel.proto === 'https').public_url;
  fs.writeFileSync('.env', `NGROK_URL=${publicUrl}\n`);
}

fetchNgrokUrl().catch(console.error);
```

Then, in your `app.config.ts`:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

interface AppConfig {
  // Define the shape of your config here
  ngrokUrl?: string;
}

function readEnvSync(): AppConfig {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const envContents = fs.readFileSync('.env', 'utf-8');
    const lines = envContents.split('\n');
    const envVars = lines.reduce((acc, line) => {
      const [key, value] = line.split('=');
      acc[key.trim()] = value.trim();
      return acc;
    }, {});
    return { ngrokUrl: envVars.NGROK_URL };
  }
  return {};
}

const config: AppConfig = readEnvSync();

export default ({ config });
```

Before running `npx expo start`, run `node setup-dev-env.js` to fetch the ngrok URL and save it to the `.env` file.

Remember to add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file to prevent committing it to your repository.

Note: "`// Define the shape of your config here`" is a placeholder comment meant to indicate where you would define the TypeScript interface for your application's configuration object.
"`Shape`" in this context refers to the structure or schema of your configuration object, which includes the types, properties, and possibly their default values that your application configuration might have.

For instance, if your application requires a base URL and an API key, you might define the shape of your config like this:

```js
interface AppConfig {
  baseUrl: string;
  apiKey: string;
  ngrokUrl?: string; // Optional property for ngrok URL
}
```

That interface `AppConfig` then is used to inform TypeScript about the properties and types you expect in your configuration object, enabling type checking and autocompletion in TypeScript-aware editors.

Comment: I was really hoping to find a way to do this within the Expo run pipeline itself but I guess I will need to perform this operation first and then run Expo. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @CMerat True, this is a workaround, which adds an extra step to the development workflow, but remains a practical solution.